# Is it necessary to write URL of webservice in each page

Tags: android

Is it necessary to write URL of web-service in each page in android application or any other way where i can save URL once for the whole application.

I have a android application where i am calling web-service . I am new to android so i don't have idea of saving the URL globally. How i can save the URL once in the whole application.

private final String URL = "http://192.1.1.1/Service1.asmx";

Instead of writing in every .java file what else i can do.

Comment: Create a new class and add public final String URL = "http://192.1.1.1/Service1.asmx"; and call from all the class like (YourClassName.URL)

Comment: Thanks ..If i want to get the URL value from application and set that value globally what code i have to write.

Comment: And in my comment there is one mistake you need to add the variable as static. public static final String URL = "192.1.1.1/Service1.asmx";

Comment: Exactly i did that its working fine.

Comment: I just add this answer as comment before the other other people answering. And you accept someone else answer. Anyway your problem solved. well fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class in java and declare a String field like the following in that class,

```
public class MyConstants {
    public static final String Url = "http://192.1.1.1/Service1.asmx";
}
```

then you can access it globally from any class like the following

```
String url = MyConstants.Url;
```

As `Url` is a static final field of MyConstants class, so you can access it just with the name of the class(without creating the object of the class with `new` Operator). i.e `MyConstants` in this case.

For Learning more about `static` and to see how this thing works, [Please refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413904/681929)

`final` means that the value cannot be changed after initialization, that's what makes it a constant. `static` means that instead of having space allocated for the field in each object, only one instance is created for the class.

So, `static final` means only one instance of the variable no matter how many objects are created and the value of that variable can never change.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a class you can just put it on `res/values/strings`

```
<string name="URLWebService">http://192.1.1.1/Service1.asmx</string>
```

Then in each class you need it do this :

```
getResources().getString(R.string.URLWebService);
```

And you can do it directly or just put a

```
public static final String URL = getResources().getString(R.string.URLWebService);
```

You can use what you want all are going to work fine.

Comment: This is the correct answer. This is is specifically what strings xml was made for.

Comment: There are lot of ways to do this, but it's the best approach you are right... :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

create a global constant class and save constants there :

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String Url = "http://192.1.1.1/Service1.asmx";
}
```

And access it anywhere in application by just calling
`Constants.Url`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `string` file in `res/values`.

You can you like following:

```
<string name="ws_url">http://192.1.1.1/Service1.asmx</string>
```

and use it so: `String wsUrl = getString(R.string.ws_url)`

Answer (score 0):

Create common class `YourGlobalClass`:

```
public class YourGlobalClass{
public static final String URL = "192.1.1.1/Service1.asmx";
}
```

And wherever you want just call the class name. your variable name
ex. `YourGlobalClass.URL;`

Comment: declare that String ***static*** i.e public static  final String URL = "192.1.1.1/Service1.asmx";

Comment: You have to put `public static final String URL = "192.1.1.1/Service1.asmx";` look at [@znobalG](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31384209/4385913) answer

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I just copy that line from the question. And I add one comments in question i did the same mistake. Thanks for noticing this.